# Looking for tool like google insights/trends but not limited to 5 comparison

Tags: seo, google

Looking for tool like google insights/trends  but not limited to 5 item per comparison + 50-100 request per account for 24 hours.

My Task  (not possible to do with google trends/insights):
take 350 keywords and sort them according search rating.
(I am doing that with php and not manually)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused. So you want to throw all 350 terms at this tool all at once, 50-100 a day? And what do you mean by "per account?"

Answer (score 2):

At a base level, I'd say there's probably no such tool that actually uses the two Google services, if only because there are no official APIs for either Trends or Insights.

But there do seem to be a bunch of hacks floating around for somewhat approximating the information, though. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635031/google-search-rankings-and-trends-api) has a link to a PHP class someone created. Assuming it still works, you might be able to mash something together. Any further exploration on this tack should probably move to StackOverflow, however.

Comment: Thanks for answer but google trends doing relative comparison between 5 items- soo because its relative numbers - not possible compare more then 5 items